# FileObserver is only called once

Tags: android

I have 1 fileObserver declared in the onCreate function of an activity. For the first time, whenever you do any change to the file directory (to be specific I delete the folder), observer works and broadcasts an intent. But from the second time onwards, observer stops working, and no intent is broadcasted. If I move the observer to onResume of the activity, it works like a charm. But as per the concept, fileobserver should continuously work in the background once it is started. I do not call stopWatching() at any place. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the first time, whenever you do any change to the file directory
>   (to be specific **I delete the folder**)

On [`DELETE_SELF`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html#DELETE_SELF) event the `FileObserver` stops itself and no new events occur, even if you create a folder with the same name later on. If you want to continue monitoring when the folder is recreated, you need to create a new `FileObserver`.

Comment: What can be done to prevent this scenario? Do I need to create the observer again and again in onResume, or some other way is possible. I tried monitoring for only FileObserver.DELETE event, but that didn't help.

Comment: I think recreating the observer is the only way. That means you need to monitor the parent folder too to know when the directory is created.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer, even I am thinking of the same, but looking for an alternative solution. Let's see if someone else can provide an alternative.

Comment: Recreating observer would cause memory leak, if it is not freed, is there any way to delete FileObserver?

Comment: According to javadocs FileObserver is garbage collected when there are no more references to it.